# get values for array

Tags: php, arrays

I am making a form in which when i submit the form i want to get the values from a array . When i `var_dump` the array i get the following result

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["s2member_level1"]=> string(3) "400" ["s2member_level2"]=> string(3) "400" ["administrator"]=> string(3) "500" } }
```

i want the values `s2members_level1 , s2members_level2 , administrator` and their values which are `440 , 400 , 500` using a for loop so that i can update these values to their records .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is 'hidden' in nested array. You can access it with `$yourData[0]`. To modify values, you can loop over the values and use reference:

```
foreach ($data[0] as $key => &$value) {
  $value = $value * 2;
}
```

In `$key` variable you will get `s2member_level1`, `s2member_level2` and `administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

well, you should use PHP's array function:

```
$myArray = array("anotherArray" => array("myDesiredValue"));

array_walk_recursive($myArray, function(&$value){
    if($value == "myDesiredValue")
    {
      $value = "ValueChanged";
    }
    });

// Now the $myArray is:
    $myArray = array("anotherArray" => array("ValueChanged"));
```

The above function loops through every individual member of all the arrays (no matter nested) and applys the changes you like. In our case, I said if the value is "myDesiredValue" then please do something. Note that I use & before `$value` in function to tell to PHP that directly change the real value of the array, so, after this function, you function is changed.